# OpenGL ES 2.0 renderbufferStorage crash

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

It seems that recently my app crashes because the renderbufferStorage method returns false. I don't know what happens, so I've added tests before but they are never raising exceptions. I'm on the main thread, the current context seems fine, the eaglLayer too, but anyway it crashes at renderbufferStorage ..

```
EAGLContext* defaultEAGLContext = getDefaultContext();
EAGLContext* currentContext = [EAGLContext currentContext];

if(![NSThread isMainThread]) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR : renderbufferStorage not called on main thread");
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"ERROR"
                                   reason:@"renderbufferStorage not called on main thread"
                                 userInfo:nil];
}

if(!currentContext) {
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"ERROR"
                                   reason:@"Current context is null"
                                 userInfo:nil];
}

if(!defaultEAGLContext) {
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"ERROR"
                                   reason:@"Default context is null"
                                 userInfo:nil];
}

if(defaultEAGLContext != currentContext) {
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"ERROR"
                                   reason:@"Default context is different than current context"
                                 userInfo:nil];
}

if(!_eaglLayer) {
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"ERROR"
                                   reason:@"EAGL layer error"
                                 userInfo:nil];
}

if (![defaultEAGLContext renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:_eaglLayer]) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR : Failed to obtain renderbuffer storage from layer");
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"ERROR"
                                   reason:@"Failed to obtain renderbuffer storage from layer"
                                 userInfo:nil];
}
```

Do you know why this method would return false, even randomly ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my init method was called two times due to some threads not being synchronized. Therefore "renderbufferStorage" was called 2 times, and the second time it was returning false because the storage was already obtained from the layer.

Answer (score 0):

You should write what the crash says but the most common mistake is forgetting to override a `layerClass` method for the target view.

The view whose layer you use in the render buffer storage must have a following override:

```
+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already have this part of code though :( . Well the method just returns false, there is no log unfortunately. It crashes after if the render buffer is not set, so I raise an exception before to retreive it with crashlytics. Is it a bad idea ?

EDIT : also it crashes randomly, some users got it but I never repro it :(

Comment: I see. So the method does not crash but returns false... Is your render buffer bound at the time?

Comment: Yes, after setting up the context (and setting it current), I bind the buffer like this : 

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_colorRenderBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderBuffer);

Comment: This is indeed a strange issue... The last thing I can come up with is the properties of the layer are incorrect or not even set. Check if you are setting some values to this view or its layer. Also check if the view is in window hierarchy.. It is actually added as a subview before this methods are called.